# Possible race condition when invoking std::packaged_task::get_future()

Tags: c++, c++11, future, race-condition

Seen at this [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future), there is a demo snippet:

```
std::packaged_task<int()> task([]{ return 7; }); // wrap the function
std::future<int> f1 = task.get_future();  // get a future
std::thread t(std::move(task)); // launch on a thread
```

My question is that whether there is any ***potential*** problems(race condition) or not if I rewrite the code snippet like this:

```
std::packaged_task<int()> task([]{ return 7; }); // wrap the function
std::thread t(std::move(task)); // firstly launch on a thread, and then gets a future
std::future<int> f1 = task.get_future();  // get a future
```

***UPDATED1***: I understand Nicol Bolas's answer, is there any ***potential*** problem(race condition) if I rewrite the code snippet like this:

```
std::packaged_task<int()> task([]{ return 7;});
thread_callablefunc_queue.push_back(task);  //task may be popped and run by another thread at once, queue is protected by mutex.
std::future<int> f1 = task.get_future();  // get a future
```

*What worries me is that the `task` may be invoked by ***another thread*** at once ***while*** the ***current thread*** is calling `task.get_future()`.*

Comment: "*thread_callablefunc_queue*" This is an unknown object, whose nature is unclear and you didn't even move into anyway. So it's unclear what the status of `task` is after this call. Also, any thread queue which doesn't take its parameters by decay-copy is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a problem. You moved the `task`. Your thread doesn't have it anymore; the `task` variable at that point is in a valid-but-unspecified state. You can't ask for its future, because it doesn't represent the task in question... because you moved it.

This isn't a race condition; it is functionally no different from this:

```
std::packaged_task<int()> task([]{ return 7; });
auto t(std::move(task));
std::future<int> f1 = task.get_future();
```

`task` has been moved from, because that's what you asked to do.

Comment: 1.auto t(std::move(task));, If I understand you correctly, the type of t is packaged_task<int()>. 2. What about the updated question(i.e. `updated1`)?